# How to get a live search feature using Jquery, AJAX, and Servlets?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have been following this guide: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2008/12/implementing-ajax-in-java-web-application-using-jquery/
When a user types a keyword in the search and presses the search button, I am able to get results back. Now, how do I make it so when the user starts typing any character, there is a post request. Right now, it uses the click function. I want to be able to get rid of the search button and let the post request occur whenever the user starts to type in a letter in the search bar.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One that uses jQuery

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Plain js

http://www.brandspankingnew.net/archive/2006/08/ajax_auto-suggest_auto-complete.html

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/life-autocomplete-textboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can use much of the same code. Just replace

```
$("#getWeatherReport").click(function(){
```

by

```
$("#cityName").keyup(function(){
```

To learn more about jQuery, I'd warmly recommend [their own tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).